# JSP: two submit button on the same form

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, servlets

I have two submit buttons on the same form in JSP page, one of each appear in the form depending on the case.

**The problem is that one of the submit buttons submit the form, and the other does not .**

here's the HTML form

```
       <form  name="stdActivationForm"  id="stdActivationForm" action="ParentManagementServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return validateStudentActivationForm()">
            <input class="${isActivated? 'hideDiv':'showDiv'}" type="submit" value="confirm"  name="submit" onclick="submitForm('add')"/>
            <input class="${parent != null? 'showDiv':'hideDiv'}" type="submit" value="update"   name="submit"  onclick="submitForm('update')"/>

        </form>
```

and here's the javascript function

```
  function submitForm(btnName)
        {
            var form = document.getElementById("stdActivationForm");
            if (btnName =='add')
                document.form.submit();
            else if(btnName =='update')
                document.form.submit();
        }
```

Comment: that is not a `JAVA` script. that is `javascript`, two completely different things....

Comment: I don't understand use of this javascript function here !! what it is written for ?

Comment: @Nael,I edit it,thanx. 
@Jigar Joshi, I found this solution in this http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/4736-Multiple-forms-in-JSP.html, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Of the same problem that I faced.

Comment: I don't see problem description on that link ? what is your problem ? can you please add it ?

Comment: Which one of the buttons is working, add or update?

Comment: Put roseindia.net in your blacklist. That site is cluttered of bad practices.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact reason, but can I ask what happens if you just have the Update button (i.e remove/comment-out the add)? Also, if they are doing the same things, why not have 1 button and just set the name of it to whatever ('Add' or 'Update') FYI: I re-tagged to javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your JavaScript function needs to return true.
Alternatively you can just remove the onclick reference and it should work with just type="submit".

Good luck.

Comment: Returning `true` is not necessary, but I agree that the whole `onclick` is completely unnecessary. The OP's issue is likely caused because `"return validateStudentActivationForm()"` returned `false`.

Comment: @BalusC, well spoted. Alaa, try removing the `onsubmit="return validateStudentActivationForm()"` for testing purposes.

Comment: @BalusC, when update btn appears it dose not call the js function validateStudentActivationForm ??!!!

Comment: Alaa, Glad to help. If it resolved your problem accept Justin answer and upvote BalusC comment, oh, and check my updated answer so that you can validate only updates for now.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `onclick`. You don't need it here. The `type="submit"` already submits the form. Your concrete problem is likely caused because the `onsubmit` of the `<form>` has returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the input type of the buttons to `"button"` and the method to:

```
function submitForm(btnName)
{
   // skip validation for updates, remove btnName =='add' && when it is working
   if (btnName =='add' && !validateStudentActivationForm())
   {
     return;      
   }   
   document.forms["stdActivationForm"].submit();
}
```

Both buttons are currently submitting to the same Servlet anyway.